# 401 Unauthorized using Guzzle but works from curl

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm trying to fetch orders data on my InfusionSoft account. I can do it using the command line but the Guzzle code gives me `401 Unathorized`. I suppose I'm doing something wrong and not able to pass the params correctly. Can someone help?

Here's what works from the command line:

```
curl -G --data "access_token=abcdefgh12345678" https://api.infusionsoft.com/crm/rest/v1/orders?limit=1&offset=100&order_by=id
```

And here's the (supposedly) equivalent code from PHP:

```
$token = 'abcdefgh12345678';
$requestBody = array('access_token' => $token);
$url = 'https://api.infusionsoft.com/crm/rest/v1/orders?limit=1&offset=100&order_by=id';
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $client->request('GET', $url, array(
    'form_params' => $requestBody
));

$response = (string) $response->getBody();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a GET request, and a GET request cannot contain a body.

`curl` uses `--data` according to the request method, so for GET it adds the access token to the URL as a GET-parameter. So should you.

Comment: Perfect, perfect, perfect! Thank you! :-)